# Leaflet HTTP.Get bad request; not loading tiles

Tags: leaflet

I am trying to walk through the Leaflet [quick start tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start.html) and am having a really simple issue: None of my tiles are loading.

I get this error at the image url and an HTTP Bad Request in the inspector:

> {"message":"id must be a string with the format account.handle"}

My code is copied and pasted straight from the tutorial:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css" />

</head>
<style>
#map { height: 180px; }
</style>


<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
</body>



<script src="//cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
<script>
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/MapID/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 18
}).addTo(map);

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was able to fix the problem by using the code inspector on the Leaflet example

The `<script>` portion looks like this:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

        L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            maxZoom: 18,
            attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
                '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
                'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
            id: 'examples.map-i86knfo3'
        }).addTo(map);
```

No idea what's triggering the issue, though.

Comment: Does it still work? I'm having the same issue with similar code.

Comment: @Carnotaurus Did you get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

When you use mapbox as your tile-source the url for your TileLayer holds your mapid prefixed with your username. For me the mapbox id would be `vannut.12345`. The id can be found within your mapbox account.

So the url  for your tile-layer would then become:

```
http://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/vannut.12345/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The reason why the other answer *is* working is because of the {id} variable within the tilelayer's URL.

```
 https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
                                 ^^^^
```

This {id} later on gets substituted by the 'id' variable in the options object:

```
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',{
 maxZoom: 18,
 attribution: '.....',
 id: 'examples.map-i86knfo3'
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Ah. So simple. It's a wonder the version above worked.

Comment: Actually it's not a wonder ;) See me updated answer.